# Change view in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have some problem at creating programmatically tab bar. I create class where create tab bar:

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

```
    let mondayTab = MondayTableViewController()
    mondayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Monday"
    mondayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let tuesdayTab = TuesdayTableViewController()
    tuesdayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Tuesday"
    tuesdayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let wednesdayTab = WednesdayTableViewController()
    wednesdayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Wednesday"
    wednesdayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let thursdayTab = TuesdayTableViewController()
    thursdayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Thursday"
    thursdayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let fridayTab = TuesdayTableViewController()
    fridayTab.tabBarItem.title = "Friday"
    fridayTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "")

    let tabBarController = [mondayTab, tuesdayTab, wednesdayTab, thursdayTab, fridayTab]
    self.viewControllers = tabBarController

}
```

In viewDidLoad I try to change starting view, using something like this:

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

but it not working...

Comment: Where are you calling tabBarController?.selectedIndex ?

Comment: In class where I create it.